# Pretty simple AngularJS Unit Test in Karma seems to fail

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My `karma.conf.coffee`:

```
module.exports = (config) ->
  config.set
    basePath: '../'

    files: [
      'public/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js'
      'public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
      'public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
      'public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js'
      'public/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js'
      'public/scripts/**/*.js'
      'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ]

    singleRun: true

    frameworks: ['jasmine']

    browsers: ['PhantomJS']

    plugins: [
      'karma-junit-reporter'
      'karma-jasmine'
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ]

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO
```

I'm testing my HeaderController which is:

```
'use strict';

angularMoonApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.init = function () {
    $rootScope.currentItem = 'home';    
  }

  $scope.init();

}]);
```

My `test/unit/controllers/header.spec.js` is:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  describe('HeaderController', function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, createController;

    beforeEach(module('angularMoon'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

      createController = function() {
        return $controller('HeaderController');
      };
    }));

    it("should set the current menu item to 'home'", function() {
      createController();
      $scope.init();

      expect($rootScope.currentItem).toBe('home');

    });

  });
})();
```

But when I executed `$ karma start test/karma.conf.coffee`, I get:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.14 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket nVTesgfm72ZGKPHrK027 with id 17114851
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) HeaderController should set the current menu item to 'home' FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35
        at c (/Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34)
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:36
        at c (/Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34)
        at d (/Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34)
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/public/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:66
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/test/unit/controllers/header.spec.js:16
        at /Users/mycomp/Sites/angular-introduction-website/test/unit/controllers/header.spec.js:21
```

So what am I doing wrong for such a simple test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass $scope to your controller in $controller. Here's a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIiWsdL83wbtzEXracSY?p=info).

```
createController = function() {
          // pass the objects you need injected in the controller.
          // including other services (if required)
        return $controller('HeaderController', {
            '$scope': $scope
        });
      };
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! As an aside - is it possible to see the tests that run instead of seeing: `PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.006 secs / 0.006 secs)`

Comment: What do you mean? The 'it' description part of the test?

Comment: Yes.. I'd like to see the `it` in the console if possible

Comment: There are a lot of "karma reporter" that you can use. start here https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-story-reporter and google if you need more. You can easily make your own reporter too!

Comment: how do you pass the objects you need injected in to the controller? Let's say, for instance, that my app uses `$firebase`.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blesh/d60fd17f0b9989fc071d/raw/basicService.spec.js Taken from http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html (very helpful blog)